# NotFound Component in React renders in every page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-component

Upon wrong URL request I am redirecting it to PageNotFound Component. Below is the code.

```
let routes = (
        <Switch>
            <React.Fragment>
            <Route path='/learning' exact component={Learning} />
            <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Route path='/home' component={Login} />
            <Route path='/about' component={Login} />
            <Route path='/profile' component={Login} />
            <Route path='/' exact component={Login} />            
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
            </React.Fragment>
        </Switch>
    );

       <BrowserRouter>            
                    <Suspense fallback={<PuffLoader color={'#000000'} size={150} css={override} loading={true} />}>
                        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                            <CssBaseline />
                            {routes}
                        </ThemeProvider>
                    </Suspense>                               
        </BrowserRouter>
```

**But when I redirect to login page two components are rendering.**
one component-> (Login Component)
second component-> (PageNotFound Component)

Any idea how to render only one component when landing upon login page and any wrong URL request I  want to redirect it to PageNotFound Component. Currently I am using below versions-->

```
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"react-router": "5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [v5.reactrouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

> How is this different than just using a bunch of `<Route>s`?
>
> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders inclusively.

So remove the `fragment` surrounds your `<Route>` it would work

```js
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router";

let routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login">
      <Login />
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <PageNotFound />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by removing <React.Fragment> and also by adding some extra code to redirect.

```
let routes = (
        <Switch>            
            <Route path='/learning' component={Learning} />
            <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
            <Route path='/home' component={Login} />
            <Route path='/about' component={Login} />
            <Route path='/profile' component={Login} />
            <Redirect from='/' to='/login' exact />            
            <Route path='*' component={PageNotFound} />            
        </Switch>
    );
```